# Akka.NET: can't send a list message to other ActorSystem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, akka, akka.net, akka-remote-actor

I'm new to Akka.NET. I have recently started to do my university project and faced the strange problem.
I have two ActorSystems in two different desktop applications. In the first ActorSystem I'm sending the message ZippedAddressListMessage between two actors using Akka.Remote.

```
public class ZippedAddressListMessage
    {
        public ZippedAddressListMessage(List<string> list)
        {
            this.Values = list.AsReadOnly();
        }

        public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Values { get; private set; }

    }
```

This works fine, but when I try to send this message to other ActorSystem, I  get the huge list of errors:
[screenshot #1 of the console window with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KZzE.jpg)

Nevertheless, if I send a simple message that consists of only one integer, all works well. It's likely that there is a serialization problem, but I couldn't figure out how it must be solved. 
I've searched everywhere, but still haven't found the answer. Please, could you explain me how to solve this issue?

**Actor from the first ActorSystem:**

```
    using Akka.Actor;
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using ChatMessages;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using Akka.Serialization;
    using Akka.Actor.Internal;
    using Akka.Remote;

namespace Agent
{
    public class ActorHelper: ReceiveActor 
    {
        int N; 
        int fromId;
        int count;
        IActorRef chiefAgent;
        List<recordItem> agentList; 
    public ActorHelper()
    {
        count = 0;
        agentList = new List<recordItem>();

        Receive<CreateHelpersMessage>(msg =>
        {
            chiefAgent = Sender;
            fromId = msg.fromID;
            N = msg.N;

            for (int i = 0; i < msg.N; i++)
            {
                Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Artemij\\Source\\Repos\\Client\\AgentHelper\\AgentHelper\\bin\\Debug\\AgentHelper.exe",
                                "akka.tcp://Agent@localhost:8000/user/AgentActor/ActorHelper" + " " + i);
            }

        });


        Receive<NewAgentHelperMessage>(msg =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg.name + " " + Sender.Path.ToString() + " || " + (count+1) + "/" + N);
            agentList.Add(new recordItem(fromId + count, msg.name, Sender));
            count++;

            Context.Watch(Sender);

            if (count == N)
            {
                chiefAgent.Tell(new AddressListMessage(agentList), Self);

            }


        });

        Receive<AddressListMessage>(msg =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("All is ready");
            List<string> temp = new List<string>();
            foreach (recordItem i in msg.Values)
            {
                temp.Add(i.ID + " " + i.name + " " + Serialization.SerializedActorPath(i.address));
            }

            foreach (recordItem i in agentList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.address);

                //PROBLEM HERE!
                i.address.Tell(new ZippedAddressListMessage(temp), Self);

            }



        });




    }

}
```

}

**Actor from other ActorSystem:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Akka.Actor;
using ChatMessages;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace AgentHelper
{

class AgentHelperActor: ReceiveActor
{
    int priority;
    ActorSelection seniorAgentActor;       
    List<recordItem> fullList;


    public AgentHelperActor(string addressSenior, string rank)
    {
        fullList = new List<recordItem>();

        seniorAgentActor = Context.ActorSelection(addressSenior);
        Int32.TryParse(rank, out priority);

        seniorAgentActor.Tell(new NewAgentHelperMessage("agent"+priority, ""), Self);

        //RECEIVING A LIST!!
        Receive<ZippedAddressListMessage>(msg =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The entire list");


        });


        Receive<NewAgentHelperMessage>(msg =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg.name);

        });


    }


    public void updateList(IReadOnlyCollection<recordItem> list)
    {
        fullList = new List<recordItem>(list);
        foreach (recordItem i in fullList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }
    }


}
```

}

**UPDATED:**
Here's a screenshot of the error at the beginning. 
[screenshot #2 of the console window with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTpJa.jpg)
It writes that format of System.String[] is not compatible with JSON serialization.

Answer (score 2):

The problem solved! The issue was about serializer: I was using Newtonsoft.Json serializer. When it comes to sending message to a remote ActorSystem, it can't serialize list. Newtonsoft explains that System.String[] is incompatible type.

The solution is to install Hyperion serializer:
http://getakka.net/docs/Serialization#how-to-setup-wire-as-default-serializer